# How to delete folders with wildcard via cmd ftp (Windows Server 2008)

Tags: ftp, windows-server-2008

I am automating a process and want to log in to an FTP, then delete all files and folders within.

How do I do this with the Commandline FTP app?

I've tried

```
mdelete *
```

but it doesn't remove the folders.

```
rmdir *
```

doesn't work with wildcards

```
mrmdir *
```

command doesn't exist

I tried moving (renaming) all folders and files to a new folder so I could delete the one folder, rename won't work with a wild card.

neither the built in `help` nor Google will tell me how to either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the parent folder rm -r {foldername} should do the trick

If you want something more advanced your best bet is a specific FTP program or roll your own batch/script file.

I think I have an old vbscript example using WMI that was based on either an MSDN or 4gusyfromrolla.com script, but I'd have to dig it out if the PS one won't work for you.

To give credit where credit is due though, my implementation is based on this powershell script
http://www.example-code.com/vb/ftpDeleteTree.asp

Comment: Have I got the wrong end of the stick? `rm -r` or `rmdir -r` isn't a CMD FTP command. Pls don't abbreviate `rmdir` either (it just confuses). Or is this only available on WS 2008?

Answer (score -1):

i was this problem in windows web server 2008 R2
problem is from firewall
in firewall some ports is disabled 
fir example after connect to host send dir command for see directory's but not work and say:
could not open data connection to port 49168: connection time out...
and also i cant use from mdelete * and mdel * and other commands
after disable firewall my problems solved!

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all: it was about finding a command that did what the OP wanted to do, not about not being able to execute commands at all.